# is this ERD(Entity Relation Diagram) is correct or not?

Tags: erd, django

I am creating an ERD for my college project. can anyone tell me if my ERD is correct or not. if not then what are my mistakes.

I am creating this ERD from django app. I generated the UML diagram with django-extension.
[image]

But still my teacher says i need to draw the ERD with rectangles identifying the Entities and such. So this is what is created
[image]

can anyone confirms if it is right or wrong??